# Want to check latency while using rosserial

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi y'all.

I recently started to run and learn ROS. 
I'm building a communication between ROS (Ubuntu 16.04.3) and Windows application by using rosserial package. 
I'm using two computers and they are connected by LAN cable. 
I was able to run sample project from the wiki. 
I want to check the latency from Windows side to ROS.
Would you give me some idea, any suggestions or experience about measuring latency?

Thank you for your time, and I appreciate in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271805/want-to-check-latency-while-using-rosserial/) by [_nobot.enter](https://answers.ros.org/users/32079/_nobot.enter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Easiest option would be to have a node send a message from one computer to the other, which then sends another one back directly. Same node that started things receives that message and compares send stamp to receive stamp. This gives you a rough estimate of the round trip time.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [_nobot.enter](https://answers.ros.org/users/32079/_nobot.enter/) on 2017-10-06**:
Thanks Stefan Kohlbrecher.
I was curious about syncing the time stamp. Does ROS sync the time stamp between server and client automatically?
Thanks again.